# Detect when OnResume is called as a result of closing permission dialog

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm refreshing a screen when OnResume is raised. The intention is to automatically refresh when a user re-opens the app when they've been away doing something else. However, it's firing merely when a permissions dialog is closed - e.g. when the app asks to send notifications. This isn't good because the refresh wipes any changes made by the user.

Is it possible to only handle OnResume when app is opened from being properly backgrounded?

Comment: Well it depends what OnResume are you talking about the XF one?

Comment: Yes. I think I'm just going to be more selective about whether a refresh occurs.

Comment: @IanWarburton Hi, not understanding *when a permissions dialog is closed* .This will be merely fired?

Comment: How are you showing the permission dialog?

Comment: It's not a problem now because I'm refreshing under much more specific conditions. However, FYI, I'm showing the permissions dialog using `CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync` from https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin. When you accept the permission, Xamarin fires the Resume event. I was surprised by this but I suppose it makes sense as it's the system returning to the app.

Comment: @IanWarburton Okey , there may be some thread conflicts between them, related to the design of CrossPermissions. If you have time, you can share the solution in the answer.

Comment: I didn’t solve it and I’m not convinced it’s a problem. I just stopped refreshing on every on resume, based on business logic.